# Is there a way to get MLKit Translations working on Vision OS for Vision Pro?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, google-mlkit, visionos

I would like to perform on device translations on the Vision Pro. The MLKit from google has a cocapods version for iOS that allows on device translation using MLkit. Since Vision OS has MLkit I believe it should work but when I try to install the cocapod, it states it cannot as visionos is not iOS. Is there a way to force install this to run or get this to run on the Vision Pro/VisionOS?

Answer (score 1):

there is a way to force a Pod to be flagged as available for other OSs, see

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12094

But in the specific case of MLKit or Firebase then you have to wait for Google to provide support for visionOS in their CocoaPods distribution as DataTransport required for MLKit does still requires a framework not Available  in visionOS and fails at build time, see

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/12591